How to run command containing string variable from string variable?
I'm trying to run command containing string variable from string variable:
$ X="bash -c 'echo OK'" ; $X
OK': -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Why doesn't it work? How to fix / do it correctly?
Note that I'm required to run command as $X.
Note that I'm required to run echo OK via bash -c.

How can we run a command stored in a variable? In short: do not store a command in a variable.

BTW, it was fun in the days of BASIC to execute code stored in a string, but it is a very unsafe technique -- an example being SQL injection attacks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

because it tries to run the command named bash -c 'echo OK'
eval $X would work

... but I would assign
X='echo OK'
and launch it as bash -c "$X"
for portability and to avoid using eval
(which usually only is required if you, in POSIX shells want do have variable names in variables and get to the contents of the "inside" variable)

Thanks. I've arrived to this: X="eval bash -c 'echo OK'" ; $X.

hmmm X="eval bash -c 'echo OK'" ; $X wouldn't work either as it would try to launch a commaned named eval bash -c 'echo OK' ...

Adding eval to the start of the variable seems to work in bash 5.2.xx at least. Something seems a little dangerous about running commands in variables though

In bash 5.1.16(1) and 5.2.15(3) the X="eval bash -c 'echo OK'" ; $X prints OK.

The post
How can we run a command stored in a variable?
contains this very long
answer by ilkkachu
which discusses the question in a very thorough manner.
I'll quote this excellent answer here.

This has been discussed in a number of questions on unix.SE, I'll try
to collect all issues I can come up with here. Below is

a description of why and how the various attempts fail,
a way to do it properly with a function (for a fixed command), or
with shell arrays (Bash/ksh/zsh) or the $@ pseudo-array (POSIX sh), both of which also allow building the command line pieces, if you
e.g. only need to vary some optoins
and notes about using eval to do this.

Some references at the end.
For the purposes here, it doesn't matter much if it's only the command
arguments or also the command name that is to be stored in a variable.
They're processed similarly up to the point where the command is
launched, at which point the shell just takes the first word as the
name of the command to run.

Why it fails
The reason you face those problems is the fact that word
splitting is quite simple and doesn't lend itself to complex
cases, and the fact that quotes expanded from variables don't act as
quotes, but are just ordinary characters.
(Note that the part about quotes is similar to every other
programming language: e.g. char *s = "foo()"; printf("%s\n", s) does
not call the function foo() in C, but just prints the string
foo(). That's different in macro processors, like m4, the C
preprocessor, or Make (to some extent). The shell is a programming
language, not a macro processor.)
On Unix-like systems, it's the shell that processes quotes and
variable expansions on the command line, turning it from a single
string into the list of strings that the underlying system call passes
to the launched command. The program itself doesn't see the quotes the
shell processed. E.g. if given the command ls -l "foo bar", the
shell turns that into the three strings ls, -l and foo bar
(removing the quotes), and passes those to ls. (Even the
command name is passed, though not all programs use it.)
The cases presented in the question:
The assignment here assigns the single string ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir" to abc:
$ abc='ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir"'

Below, $abc is split on whitespace, and ls gets the three
arguments -l, "/tmp/test/my and dir". The quotes here are just
data, so there's one at the front of the second argument and another
at the back of the third. The option works, but the path gets
incorrectly processed as ls sees the quotes as part of the
filenames:
$ $abc
ls: cannot access '"/tmp/test/my': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'dir"': No such file or directory

Here, the expansion is quoted, so it's kept as a single word. The
shell tries to find a program literally called ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir", spaces and quotes included.
$ "$abc"
bash: ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir": No such file or directory

And here, $abc is split, and only the first resulting word is taken
as the argument to -c, so Bash just runs ls in the current
directory. The other words are arguments to bash, and are used to fill
$0, $1, etc.
$ bash -c $abc
'my dir'

With bash -c "$abc", and eval "$abc", there's an additional shell
processing step, which does make the quotes work, but also causes all
shell expansions to be processed again, so there's a risk of
accidentally running e.g. a command substitution from user-provided
data, unless you're very careful about quoting.

Better ways to do it
The two better ways to store a command are a) use a function instead,
b) use an array variable (or the positional parameters).
Using functions:
Simply declare a function with the command inside, and run the
function as if it were a command. Expansions in commands within the
function are only processed when the command runs, not when it's
defined, and you don't need to quote the individual commands. Though
this really only helps if you have a fixed command  you need to store
(or more than one fixed command).
# define it
myls() {
    ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir"
}

# run it
myls

It's also possible to define multiple functions and use a variable to
store the name of the function you want to run in the end.
Using an array:
Arrays allow creating multi-word variables where the individual words
contain white space. Here, the individual words are stored as distinct
array elements, and the "${array[@]}" expansion expands each element
as separate shell words:
# define the array
mycmd=(ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir")

# expand the array, run the command
"${mycmd[@]}"

The command is written inside the parentheses exactly as it would be
written when running the command. The processing the shell does is the
same in both cases, just in one it only saves the resulting list of
strings, instead of using it to run a program.
The syntax for expanding the array later is slightly horrible, though,
and the quotes around it are important.
Arrays also allow you to build the command line piece-by-piece. For
example:
mycmd=(ls)               # initial command
if [ "$want_detail" = 1 ]; then
    mycmd+=(-l)          # optional flag, append to array
fi
mycmd+=("$targetdir")    # the filename

"${mycmd[@]}"

or keep parts of the command line constant and use the array fill just
a part of it, like options or filenames:
options=(-x -v)
files=(file1 "file name with whitespace")
target=/somedir

somecommand "${options[@]}" "${files[@]}" "$target"

(somecommand being a generic placeholder name here, not any
real command.)
The downside of arrays is that they're not a standard feature, so
plain POSIX shells (like dash, the default /bin/sh in
Debian/Ubuntu) don't support them (but see below). Bash, ksh and zsh
do, however, so it's likely your system has some shell that supports
arrays.
Using "$@"
In shells with no support for named arrays, one can still use the
positional parameters (the pseudo-array "$@") to hold the arguments
of a command.
The following should be portable script bits that do the equivalent of
the code bits in the previous section. The array is replaced with
"$@", the list of positional parameters.  Setting "$@" is done
with set, and the double quotes around "$@" are important (these
cause the elements of the list to be individually quoted).
First, simply storing a command with arguments in "$@" and running
it:
set -- ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir"
"$@"

Conditionally setting parts of the command line options for a command:
set -- ls
if [ "$want_detail" = 1 ]; then
    set -- "$@" -l
fi
set -- "$@" "$targetdir"

"$@"

Only using "$@" for options and operands:
set -- -x -v
set -- "$@" file1 "file name with whitespace"
set -- "$@" /somedir

somecommand "$@"

Of course, "$@" is usually filled with the arguments to the script
itself, so you'll have to save them somewhere before re-purposing
"$@".
To conditionally pass a single argument, you can also use the
alternate value expansion ${var:+word} with some careful quoting.
Here, we include -f  and the filename only if the filename is
nonempty:
file="foo bar"
somecommand ${file:+-f "$file"}


Using eval (be careful here!)
eval takes a string and runs it as a command, just like if it was
entered on the shell command line. This includes all quote and
expansion processing, which is both useful and dangerous.
In the simple case, it allows doing just what we want:
cmd='ls -l "/tmp/test/my dir"'
eval "$cmd"

With eval, the quotes are processed, so ls eventually sees just
the two arguments -l and /tmp/test/my dir, like we want. eval is
also smart enough to concatenate any arguments it gets, so eval $cmd
could also work in some cases, but e.g. all runs of whitespace would
be changed to single spaces. It's still better to quote the variable
there as that will ensure it gets unmodified to eval.
However, it's dangerous to include user input in the command string
to eval. For example, this seems to work:
read -r filename
cmd="ls -ld '$filename'"
eval "$cmd";

But if the user gives input that contains single quotes, they can break out of the quoting and run arbitrary commands! E.g. with the
input '$(whatever)'.txt, your script happily runs the command
substitution. That it could have been rm -rf (or worse) instead.
The issue there is that the value of $filename was embedded in the
command line that eval runs. It was expanded before eval, which
saw e.g. the command ls -l ''$(whatever)'.txt'. You would need to
pre-process the input to be safe.
If we do it the other way, keeping the filename in the variable, and
letting the eval command expand it, it's safer again:
read -r filename
cmd='ls -ld "$filename"'
eval "$cmd";

Note the outer quotes are now single quotes, so expansions within do
not happen. Hence, eval sees the command ls -l "$filename" and
expands the filename safely itself.
But that's not much different from just storing the command in a
function or an array. With functions or arrays, there is no such
problem since the words are kept separate for the whole time, and
there's no quote or other processing for the contents of filename.
read -r filename
cmd=(ls -ld -- "$filename")
"${cmd[@]}"

Pretty much the only reason to use eval is one where the varying
part involves shell syntax elements that can't be brought in via
variables (pipelines, redirections, etc.). However, you'll then need
to quote/escape everything else on the command line that needs
protection from the additional parsing step (see link below). In any
case, it's best to avoid embedding input from the user in the
eval command!

References

Word Splitting in BashGuide
BashFAQ/050 or "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"
The question Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?, which discusses a number of issues related to
quoting and whitespace, including storing commands.
Escape a variable for use as content of another script
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562870/170373


